# add unique Elements to List/HashSet of User defined class (i.e. List<Operand> )

Tags: c#

add unique Elements to List of User defined class (i.e. List )

```
public class Operand: IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{ 
public String opr;
public String state;
}
```

i want made it and implement all necessary routines to apply List on it. 
(Note : class Operand: IEnumerable, IEnumerator )

but when i am Trying to add elements ie Operand 's object
operand tem1=new Operand("eax","undef");

```
operand tem2=new Operand("ebx","undef");

operand tem3=new Operand("ecx","undef");

operand tem4=new Operand("eax","undef");
operand tem5=new Operand("eax","undef");
```

then i want to add these 5 temp[1-5] elements in List OR HashSet.
and if there is duplicate element the update the **state** of that element to Def i.e.Define

how do i do it...
please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Operand` class override the `GetHashCodeMethod` and `Equals` method. Make sure you return a unique HashCode for unique `Operand` instance and also make sure if two operands are same i.e. their property values are same return true in equals method and false otherwise

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj is Operand)
            {
                Operand op = obj as Operand;
                if (this.opr == op.opr && this.state == op.state)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

  public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + opr.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + state.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

After implementing these method you can check for duplicate in the `List` of `Hashset` by using `Contains` method. If you find the duplicate instead of inserting new record update the existing one.

Answer (score -2):

Put this code in a operand.java file:

```
public class Operand
{ 
public String opr;
public String state;
}
```

Now in other bean.java file write this code

```
public class bean {
    List<operand> mylist = new ArrayList<operand>();
    String[] opr = new String[]{"eax","ecx","eax","eax"};
    String[] state = new String[]{"def","def","def","def"};
    operand[] o = new operand[4];
    public bean() {
        for (int i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
            o[i] = new operand();
            o[i].setCity(opr[i]);
            o[i].setName(state[i]);
            mylist.add(o[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it will work for you problem, try it out.

Comment: `Put this code in a operand.java file:` the problem is C# based not Java